# Why the weight of CNN from keras is only one-dimensional?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I built a CNN using `keras` and saved the weight in a *.hdf file. I used `16` filters and the size of the kernel is `3×3`. 
But the output of `save_weight` for the first `Convolution2D` is only `1×16`. The size of kernel is `3×3`, so the output should be `3×3×16`, shouldn't it? Why does the output behave like this?

This is the screenshot of the structure of *.hdf file:

[image]

Comment: How do you know the size of the saved weights inside the `*.hdf` file?

Comment: I used the HDF Explorer to view the hdf file

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the structure of your `*.hdf` file?

Comment: I showed the screenshot in the answer of the question.

Comment: Please show us all entries of the `convolution2d_1` entry by adding a new screenshot to your first post.

Comment: what else do you want ? The screenshot  I showed is the all kernel matrix of  'convolution2d_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: If you use `16` filters with a size of `3x3` you will see `16x3x6` weights. When I open a `*.h5` file of the `VGG16` network from [here](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3) with the free `HDFView` tool, the convolutions have this weights:

> 32-bit floating-point,   64 x 3 x 3 x 3
>
> 32-bit floating-point    64

for this layer

```
Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu')
```

Therefore, I think that you are using your `HDF Explorer` wrong (this is why I asked for more screenshots). Please try to open the network file in the referenced gist, and check, if you see the weights with the same dimensions using your tool.